# Publish to AppCenter Android cannot find my .apk

Tags: android, xamarin, azure-devops, azure-pipelines

I'm trying to publish my android app to AppCenter. It can't seem to find my .apk file which is strange. My APK file gets created when I'm running the android build task. I don't know whether I've set the configurations wrong in my visual studio.

[Pipeline fail error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/s4YO8.png)

Here's my raw log from the android build on the pipeline:

```
Copying file from "/Users/runner/work/1/s/PizzaHutOLO/PizzaHutOLO.Android/obj/CI/android/bin/PizzaHutOLO.Android.apk" to "/Users/runner/work/1/s/PizzaHutOLO/PizzaHutOLO.Android/bin/CI/PizzaHutOLO.Android.apk".
2021-07-07T13:12:46.5639610Z _CreateAndroidDebugSigningKey:
2021-07-07T13:12:46.5642400Z   /Users/runner/hostedtoolcache/Java_Adopt_jdk/8.0.292-10/x64/Contents/Home/bin/keytool -genkeypair -alias androiddebugkey -storepass android -keypass android -keystore "/Users/runner/.local/share/Xamarin/Mono for Android/debug.keystore" -dname "CN=Android Debug,O=Android,C=US" -keyalg RSA -validity 10950 -storetype pkcs12 
2021-07-07T13:12:53.5399160Z _ResolveAndroidSigningKey:
2021-07-07T13:12:53.5399730Z   Creating "obj/CI/android_debug_keystore.flag" because "AlwaysCreate" was specified.
2021-07-07T13:12:53.5437110Z _Sign:
2021-07-07T13:12:53.5439120Z   /Users/runner/Library/Android/sdk/build-tools/30.0.2/zipalign -p 4 "/Users/runner/work/1/s/PizzaHutOLO/PizzaHutOLO.Android/obj/CI/android/bin/PizzaHutOLO.Android.apk" "bin/CI//PizzaHutOLO.Android-Signed.apk" 
2021-07-07T13:12:53.9895870Z   /Users/runner/hostedtoolcache/Java_Adopt_jdk/8.0.292-10/x64/Contents/Home/bin/java -jar /Library/Frameworks/Xamarin.Android.framework/Libraries/xbuild/Xamarin/Android/apksigner.jar sign --ks "/Users/runner/.local/share/Xamarin/Mono for Android/debug.keystore" --ks-pass pass:android --ks-key-alias androiddebugkey --key-pass pass:android --min-sdk-version 29 --max-sdk-version 29  /Users/runner/work/1/s/PizzaHutOLO/PizzaHutOLO.Android/bin/CI/PizzaHutOLO.Android-Signed.apk 
2021-07-07T13:12:56.1897910Z   Signed android package 'bin/CI/PizzaHutOLO.Android-Signed.apk'
```

So far I've tried these in the binary file path:

**/*/Signed.apk

$(build.binariesdirectory)/CI/PizzaHutOLO.Android.apk

Answer (score 0):

The build output says your signed APK is in

**bin**/CI/PizzaHutOLO.Android-Signed.apk

Try

$(build.binariesdirectory)/**bin**/CI/PizzaHutOLO.Android.apk